# get node text() with or without anchor tag

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I can't figure out how to get a table cell's text() whether or not an anchor tag is parent to the text.

WITH:

```
    <td class="c divComms" title="Komentarz|"> 
<a id="List1_Dividends_ctl01_HyperLink1" target="_blank" href="http://www.attrader.pl/pl/akcje/DRUKPAK/komunikat/EBI/none,20130104_090845_0000041461">uchwalona</a> 
<div class="stcm">2013-01-29</div></td>
```

WITHOUT:

```
<td class="c divComms" title="Komentarz|Celem...">
proponowana
<div class="stcm">2012-10-05</div>
</td>
```

Composing elements of a hash, I would expect

```
 details = rows.collect do |row|
  detail = {}
  [
     [:paystatus, 'td[7]//text()[not(ancestor::div)]'],
     [:paydate, 'td[7]/div/text()'], # the 2013-01-29 or 2012-10-05 above
  ].each do |name, xpath|
    detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
  end
```

to catch either *uchwalona* or *proponowana* (notice without the date in the trailing div), but as it stands, it ignores the `a` tag text, unless I do `td[7]/a/text()`, in which case *only* the anchor's text "uchwalona" is read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the union operator | should work:

```
[:paystatus, '(td[7]|td[7]/a)/text()']
```

(I think you won't need the `[not(ancestor::div)]` part if you don't use a double-slash)

Comment: `(td[7]|td[7]/a)/text()` still seems to catch only the non-anchors (and I removed `[not(ancestor::div)]` for testing)

Comment: Thanks. After applying the union, the problem seemed to be related to using `#at_xpath` instead of `#xpath`, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14414247/1069375

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be resolved when I used the `row.xpath` method instead of `.at_xpath`, which somehow made the union operator **`|`** ineffective.

So changed

```
  detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
```

to:

```
  detail[name] = row.xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
```

This meant I also had to tighten a few xpath expressions in my other field `|name, xpath|` pairs, to not over-include as unnoticed before.

Comment: It's not that the union operator was ineffective, it's the fact that `at_xpath` returns a single node, even if multiple match.